# Limiting number of result from each category, advise needed

Tags: php, mysql, shuffle

I have this code

```
<?php
function Random($numchar)  
{  
$categories = "83 76 168 102";  
$array=explode(" ",$categories);  
shuffle($array);  
$newstring = implode($array,",");
return substr($newstring, 0, $numchar);  

}
$numbers = Random(216);
$res = str_replace(",","','",$numbers);
$cats = '\''.$res.'\'';
$news = mysql_query("SELECT 
item.id AS itemid, 
item.cid AS itemcid, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(item.url, '/', 3) AS itemurl, 
item.title AS itemtitle, 
item.top AS itemtop, 
images.id AS imgid, 
images.img AS imagesimg, 
images.item_id AS imagesitemid,
folders.id AS foldersid,
channels.id AS channelsid,
channels.parent AS channelsparent
FROM item, images, folders, channels 
WHERE 
item.id = images.item_id
AND item.cid = channels.id
AND channels.parent = folders.id
AND channels.parent = '$cat'
AND FIELD(item.cid, $cats)
ORDER BY 
itemtop DESC, RAND(), images.item_id DESC 
LIMIT 20");

?>
```

Every time the page is refreshed, the code returns 20 items from one of categories defined within variable $categories. I would like to display only 5 items from each category. Is it possible with a single query as I intended? I want to make room so items from all categories can be shown equally.

Is there any other way I could optimized the query?

Comment: why then not `LIMIT 5`?

Comment: 5 would show 5 items from a single category, and I'll have to create 3 other queries for other categories. The problem is when the categories become 50 categories, I can't write 50 queries on the same page.

Comment: You might be able to do it via using multiple join queries on the same table - one per category.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get 5 items from each category you will have to run seperate sub query to each category with a limit of 5 and then combine them all together. Here is an example:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  (SELECT
    item.id AS itemid, 
    item.cid AS itemcid, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(item.url, '/', 3) AS itemurl, 
    item.title AS itemtitle, 
    item.top AS itemtop, 
    images.id AS imgid, 
    images.img AS imagesimg, 
    images.item_id AS imagesitemid,
    folders.id AS foldersid,
    channels.id AS channelsid,
    channels.parent AS channelsparent
  FROM
    item,
    images,
    folders,
    channels
  WHERE 
    item.id = images.item_id
    AND item.cid = channels.id
    AND channels.parent = folders.id
    AND channels.parent = '$cat[0]'
    AND FIELD(item.cid, $cats[0])
  LIMIT 5)

  UNION ALL

  (SELECT
    item.id AS itemid, 
    item.cid AS itemcid, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(item.url, '/', 3) AS itemurl, 
    item.title AS itemtitle, 
    item.top AS itemtop, 
    images.id AS imgid, 
    images.img AS imagesimg, 
    images.item_id AS imagesitemid,
    folders.id AS foldersid,
    channels.id AS channelsid,
    channels.parent AS channelsparent
  FROM
    item,
    images,
    folders,
    channels
  WHERE 
    item.id = images.item_id
    AND item.cid = channels.id
    AND channels.parent = folders.id
    AND channels.parent = '$cat[1]'
    AND FIELD(item.cid, $cats[1])
  LIMIT 5)

  UNION ALL

  (SELECT
    item.id AS itemid, 
    item.cid AS itemcid, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(item.url, '/', 3) AS itemurl, 
    item.title AS itemtitle, 
    item.top AS itemtop, 
    images.id AS imgid, 
    images.img AS imagesimg, 
    images.item_id AS imagesitemid,
    folders.id AS foldersid,
    channels.id AS channelsid,
    channels.parent AS channelsparent
  FROM
    item,
    images,
    folders,
    channels
  WHERE 
    item.id = images.item_id
    AND item.cid = channels.id
    AND channels.parent = folders.id
    AND channels.parent = '$cat[2]'
    AND FIELD(item.cid, $cats[2])
  LIMIT 5)
)sub_query

ORDER BY 
  itemtop DESC, RAND(), sub_query.item_id DESC
```

You may want to add an order by within the subquery to define which 5 are returned for each category. You may also need to rework how your `$cat` is being defined. Hope this helps.

Comment: @D_Guy13 you can write this query with a loop for every category if desired by using `foreach($cat as $value){` and then pre-pend and post-pend the beginning and ending of the query by using `$query .="beginning of query"` then execute `$news = mysql_query($query);`

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with user variables... not sure how/if php will handle it, but with raw sql something like this should work (not tested, but you should get the idea, see http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/ for more details):

```
set @num := 0, @cid := '';

SELECT 
item.id AS itemid, 
item.cid AS itemcid, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(item.url, '/', 3) AS itemurl, 
item.title AS itemtitle, 
item.top AS itemtop, 
images.id AS imgid, 
images.img AS imagesimg, 
images.item_id AS imagesitemid,
folders.id AS foldersid,
channels.id AS channelsid,
channels.parent AS channelsparent,
@num := if(@cid = item.cid, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
@cid := cid as dummy
FROM item, images, folders, channels 
WHERE 
item.id = images.item_id
AND item.cid = channels.id
AND channels.parent = folders.id
AND channels.parent = '$cat'
AND FIELD(item.cid, $cats)
ORDER BY 
itemtop DESC GROUP, RAND(), images.item_id DESC
GROUP BY item.id, item.cid, item.title
having row_number <= 5;
```